# GPUImage 2 video inputs

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I am trying to blend 2 videos together using `GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter`. The ouput looks like what I want but there are some frames are put out of their time. For example, a frame at time 0.32 is put at time 0.4. You can look at this [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7VVwTE5jOw&feature=youtu.be) for an exact details. This time mismatch makes the video looks not good, so I hope somebody could help me.

I try to look deep into the file `GPUImageTwoInputFilter`, method

`- (void)newFrameReadyAtTime:(CMTime)frameTime atIndex:(NSInteger)textureIndex;`

And try to change this line:

`[super newFrameReadyAtTime:frameTime atIndex:0];`
But if I change `frameTime` into `firstFrameTime`, the second video has time mismatch problems, if I change it to `secondFrameTime`, the first video has time mismatch problems.

Comment: Hi, I'm having exactly the same issue trying to blend 2 videos into one using GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter. Did you find a way to solve the issue? Thanks!